# Programatically get a list of node ids of a content type for a specified language

Tags: database, i18n-l10n

From the following code I get all the node ids of content type 'blog'

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $query->condition('type', 'blog');
    $query->sort('created', 'ASC');
    $entity_ids = $query->execute();
```

I want to retrieve all the node ids of specific language. 
Eg. Node ids of content type 'blog' for 'French' language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add `langcode` to the query:

```
$query->condition('langcode', 'fr');
```